# Perl tr usage of regexp

Tags: regex, perl

i would like to ask about regex usage in Perl, extacly the tr///

So if i have an expression 
tr/abcde/abc the result will be abcab? 
How extacly the tr works?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_tr.htm

Comment: `tr///` does not use regular expressions. It's documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2f_SEARCHLIST_%2f_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2fcdsr).

Comment: Did you do anything to find an answer in the documentation? It's not hidden, and it's where I would expect it to be -- in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2f_SEARCHLIST_%2f_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2fcdsr)

Comment: If the replacement list on the right is too short, the last character is replicated to match the length of the search list on the left, so your `tr` is equivalent to:  `tr/abcde/abccc/`.  Each character in the search list on the left is replaced by the corresponding character in the replacement list on the right.  If you apply your `tr` to the string: `"a-c-b-d-e-f-g"`, the string will be changed to: `"a-c-b-c-c-f-g"`, and the return value of the `tr` expression will be 5, indicating the number of substitutions performed on the string.

Comment: If you wanted to replace each of the characters "abcde" with "x", you could use: `tr/abcde/x/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr///` has nothing to do with regular expressions. `tr///` is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

```
my $x = "aabbccddee!";
$x =~ tr/abc/xyz/;
say $x;   # xxyyzzddee
```

Comment: I just would like to add something about tr, if we have something like this

my $x = "abcde";
$x =~ tr/abc//;
say $x;   # abcde

If you use tr without second argument, the string that you work on, doesn't change. Just in case someone need that information.

Comment: It does if you use /d